# Change time value in database using postgresql and python

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a database that was created by a program (python)  . I must change a column that contains time value. The column is empty in creation of database, and my program ask to user a date which is used in 2 columns. First one to specify the start time and the second one is end time. End time is more 30 days than the start time.

Here my problem : how can i add 30 days to the start time in my code ?

Answer (score 1):

In Python there is `datetime.timedelta`, eg:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()
nowand30 = now + timedelta(days=30)
```

In SQL, you can do:

```
DATE(some_date_val + 30 days)
```

or:

```
some_date_val + interval '30 days'
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try this, but the documentation says:

```
date '2001-09-28' + integer '7'
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html

Comment: thanks, i saw this one but i didn't understand how i can use it in python code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add 30 to the date:

```
update the_table
   set start_time = start_time + 30;
```

or if you want it more explicetly:

```
update the_table
   set start_time = start_time + interval '30' day;
```

The same way you can add different units:

```
update the_table
   set start_time = start_time + interval '30' minute;
```

(assuming start_time is a timestamp column)